# A big list of every keyval package

Tags: big-list, key-value, xkeyval

I lose track of all the different keyval packages. Can we maintain a list here? (Community wiki, one package per answer with a brief description of scope. I've started things off but need help completing it.)

Comment: This should be converted to a TUGboat article.

Comment: @Martin — as soon as we'd do that someone would write another one! :)

Comment: i'd second what @will says: i constructed a list, but in two months, two more (getoptk -- a slightly weird thing, and ltxkeys) have appeared.

Comment: Why are there (more than) 13 keyval packages anyway?

Comment: See also the survey article http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf

Comment: @You - Some of the packages emerged from a desire to address a shortcoming identified with an existing package, to add features to an existing package, to attend to a personal need (or even desire) of the author or of a requestor, or simply to experiment with coding.

Comment: Wow. I've just seen this. Another reason to prefer ConTeXt unified treatment of key-value pairs. Btw, do ConTeXt modules count as answers?

Comment: @JairoADelRio Not much point IMO. FWIW you could say this about any active area of LaTeX development. Because LaTeX has a smaller core and a much larger ecosystem, of course there are going to be more solutions to common problems. Also notable that of the 18 packages listed below, 6 are by one author and not much used, and others are more about interfacing keyval into class/package options rather than new keyval approaches per se.

Comment: The following topic “[Key-Val: packages with key-value argument systems](https://www.ctan.org/topic/keyval)” on CTAN also gives a good overview of the available keyval packages.

Answer (score 25):

## [pgfkeys.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys), part of PGF/TikZ

Author: Till Tantau

Comment: I marked this entry up---it also counts for adding the other entries:-)

Answer (score 16):

## [kvoptions.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions)

Author: Heiko Oberdiek

Supports keyval processing of package/class options.

[Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/kvoptions/kvoptions.pdf)

Answer (score 16):

## [l3keys.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel), part of expl3

Author: Joseph Wright (through the LaTeX3 Project)

Inspired by `pgfkeys`.

Use `l3keys2e` to use it in options of LaTeX2e packages and classes.

Answer (score 13):

## [keyval.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/keyval)

Author: David Carlisle

The original and (probably) most widely used keyval package. Provides `\define@key` and `\setkeys` but all processing for special key-types must be done manually.

Removes one or two layers of braces around each "val".

Note: this package can have scope problems with nesting `\setkeys`. Nowadays I'd recommend a more modern alternative.

Comment: The *keyval* package strips off 2 levels of outer brace: one by using the space trimmer \KV@@sp@def and one in internal parsing.

Answer (score 12):

## LaTeX kernel

The LaTeX kernel's June 2022 update added key=val functionality (outside of `expl3`'s `l3keys`), that is functionally equivalent to `l3keys`.

Defining keys is possible via `\DeclareKeys[<module>]{<key-definitions>}`, setting via `\SetKeys[<module>]{<key=val-list>}`.

Package and class options are supported via `\ProcessKeyOptions[<module>]`.

Comment: Is there a good doc about this?

Comment: @projetmbc documentation is in the making, should be added to `usrguide3`/`usrguide`. Currently you can fancy a peek in `source2e` in the `ltkeys`-section. There is also an intention to add documentation to `clsguide`.

Comment: @projetmbc usage example on this site is available [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648001/117050). The `<module>` argument defaults to the current file name.

Comment: So cute! I like that and will test it soon.

Comment: It would be great to have the minimum LaTeX version where this is available.

Comment: @JérômeLAURENS the June 2022 release, see ltnews 35.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the answer

Answer (score 8):

## [xkeyval.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval)

Author: Hendri Adriaens

Cannot be loaded before `\documentclass`.

Note: in the past controversial because it overwrites `keyval`'s `\setkeys` macro and in some cases caused (long-standing) incompatibilities. But I believe any problems resulting from this are now fixed.

Comment: The *xkeyval* package strips off precisely 3 levels of outer braces in key values: one by using *keyval’s* space trimmer \KV@@sp@def and two in internal parsing. The *keyreader* package addresses this problem. Another problem with the *xkeyval* package is that its `\setkeys` command doesn't accept unbalanced conditionals. For example, `\setkeys[KV]{fam}{key=\iffalse}` fails. The next release of *keyreader* addresses this problem in its `\krdsetkeys` command. The *selective sanitization* scheme of *xkeyval* also appears unduly expensive when there are active commas and equals sign in key-vals.

Comment: Much of the reported incompatibility issue with *xkeyval's* `\setkeys` seems to have disappeared, even for keys defined by David Carlisle's original `\define@key`. *kvsetkeys* package later replaced its `\setkeys` with `\kvsetkeys`.

Comment: Is there any particular *reason* why it can't be loaded before \documentclass?

Comment: Yes, by design. xkeyval needs to know the documentclass options for inheritance purposes. Not sure from a technical standpoint, though, why it can't pick them up along the way; haven't looked into the details recently.

Comment: *xkeyval.sty* (not *xkeyval.tex*) needs the `\@classoptionslist` macro for (1) filtering `=<value>` from the class options list and (2) for class and package options processing with `\ProcessOptionsX*`. The *keyreader* packages delays the search for `\@classoptionslist` and the actions mentioned at (1) and (2) above until `\documentclass` was instantiated later by the document.

Answer (score 7):

## [scrbase.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrbase)

Author: Markus Kohm

It's part of KOMA-Script and documented in [scrguide-en.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) (English) and [scrguide-de.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-de.pdf) (German). It provides a family hierarchy for key-values and a processing of class and package options. With newer LaTeX kernels it uses the new raw option feature for key-value-options, but still provides a complex (but not easy to understand) feature to report unprocessed values. It also provides several types of values, like integers, length, strings, switches and a mapping from symbolic to numeric values.

<sub>I never used it my self so I can’t say more about it …</sub>

Answer (score 6):

## [kvsetkeys.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/kvsetkeys)

Author: Heiko Oberdiek

Comment: *kvsetkeys* only sets keys; it doesn't define them. It strips one level of outer curly braces in key values.

Answer (score 6):

## [keyreader.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/keyreader)

Author: Ahmed Musa

The package provides a robust interface to controlling keys in `xkeyval`, removing some of that package’s restrictions.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: done!

Comment: @Ahmed — your comments should be additional answers on this page!

Comment: Also, this page is supposed to be comprehensive. It makes no sense to remove an entry! I've added `skeyval` below.

Answer (score 6):

## [pgfopts.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts)

Author: Joseph Wright

Allows `pgfkeys` processing to be performed on class or package options.

Comment: It's not really a keyval package :-)

Comment: Counts for me :)

Answer (score 5):

## [yax.tex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/yax)

Author: Paul Isambert

Part of the author's collection of plain tex/generic packages.

Looks nice, but I've never used the macros.  Syntax highly eccentric, as viewed by a latex user...

Answer (score 5):

## [`expkv`-bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/expkv-bundle)

Author: Jonathan P. Spratte

`expkv` is the only fully expandable key=val parser (in addition to the basic `\keyval_parse:NNn` of `l3keys` which was modelled after `expkv`'s implementation of `\ekvparse`).

The bundle consists of multiple packages:

### `expkv`

The package alone does only provide features comparable with `keyval` (the macros are called `\ekvdef`, `\ekvdefNoVal`, and `\ekvset`), but it does only strip one set of braces and only after spaces are stripped, and it does work for active commas and equals signs. As of writing this, it is the fastest key=val parser with robust parsing (in the sense of the aforementioned brace and category code safety).

Additional utility packages by the same author are available to extend `expkv`'s features:

### `expkv-def`

Provides key-types similar to `pgfkeys` or `l3keys`, definable in a key=val interface. Many of the key types aren't expandable (because they do assignments).

### `expkv-cs`

Define expandable macros with a key=val argument. The package allows two different syntax variants, one will split the keys into separate arguments (`#1` ... `#9`) the other will provide a list in which values can be accessed by the key names.

### `expkv-opt`

Parse LaTeX class and package options with `expkv`.

---

<sub>Except for `expkv-opt` all the packages can be used in plainTeX, LaTeX, and ConTeXt.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

## [keycommand.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/keycommand)

Author: Florent Chervet

Answer (score 2):

## [pgfkeyx.sty](http://ctan.tug.org/pkg/pgfkeyx)

Author: Ahmed Musa

From the package description:

> The package extends and improves the robustness of the pgfkeys package. In particular, it can deal with active comma, equality sign, and slash in key parsing. The difficulty with active characters has long been a problem with the pgfkeys package.

With any luck, this facility can be merged into the main code of pdfkeys directly. Unless this robustifying is too resource intensive, I supposed.

**Edits by Skillmon:**

Up to today (2020-06-23) this package wasn't integrated into `pgfkeys`. It fixes two of the bugs `pgfkeys` has (I only know of these two bugs), namely it doesn't strip any braces before space stripping, and it works even if commas or equals signs are made active.

Starting with commit [1e520dc7](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/1e520dc7) to `pgfkeys`, `pgfkeyx` is no longer compatible with it.

The author's statement

> *pgfkeyx* is not any significantly more resource-intensive than the original *pgfkeys*.

however isn't true. The following shows the results of benchmarking `pgfkeys` and `pgfkeyx`. The dots are the benchmarking results, the lines are the interpolations on them, linear for `pgfkeys` (blue) and quadratic for `pgfkeyx` (red).

[image]

Comment: The integration of *pgfkeyx* with *pgfkeys* was suggested by the author of *pgfkeyx*. *pgfkeyx* is not any significantly more resource-intensive than the original *pgfkeys*.

Comment: Is this package still needed or has it been integrated?

Comment: The two packages probably still differ I'd guess. Perhaps @JosephWright knows more?

Comment: @cfr if you're still interested, see my edits.

Answer (score 2):

## [options](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/options)

Author: Daan Leijen

Inspired by `pgfkeys` and in fact very similar, but faster. It also supports parsing class and package options.

Answer (score 2):

## Opmac tricks 0069 and 0114, OpTeX trick 0008

Author: Petr Olsak.

OPmac tricks [0069](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#keyval) and [0114](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#flags) are usable for plain TeX with OPmac macros, OpTeX trick [0008](http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#keyval) is intended for OpTeX format.

Answer (score 1):

## [keyval2e.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/keyval2e)

Author: Ahmed Musa

This was meant to be lightweight, with no facility for options processing.

Comment: Shouldn't be used as it loads the [problematic `catoptions` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=catoptions).

Answer (score 1):

## [ltxkeys.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxkeys)

Author: Ahmed Musa

*ltxkeys*, unlike *keyreader*, is completely independent of *xkeyval* and provides many more features. It can be loaded before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Shouldn't be used as it loads the [problematic `catoptions` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=catoptions).

Answer (score 1):

## [skeycommand.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skeycommand)

Author: Ahmed Musa

Superceded by ltxkeys.

Comment: Much of the functionality of *skeycommand* has been moved to *ltxkeys*, as indicated in the sub-title of *skeycommand* documentation. But my recent experience shows that it's nearly impossible to abandon a package, once it has been released to CTAN. It will resurface somewhere someday.

Comment: Shouldn't be used as it loads the [problematic `catoptions` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=catoptions).

Answer (score 1):

## [skeyval.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/skeyval)

Author: Ahmed Musa

**The package (version 1.3) is incompatible with LaTeX 2020/10/01 and newer**

The skeyval package provides commands for compactly defining and
initializing all types of key (ordinary, command, boolean, style, choice,
etc). It attempts to combine the features of ltxkeys package (which has
the syntax of the xkeyval package) and pgfkeys package. See [Possibility to pass options to packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66591/possibility-to-pass-options-to-packages).

Comment: Shouldn't be used as it loads the [problematic `catoptions` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=catoptions).

Answer (score 1):

## [simplekv](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/simplekv)

Author: Christian Tellechea

Documentation is only available in French. It is pretty fast and unconventional in the way undefined keys are handled (they get stored as new keys and no error is thrown).

Answer (score 1):

## [luakeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luakeys)

Author: Josef Friedrich

A Lua module for parsing key-value options

### Pros

- Key-value pairs can be parsed independently of the macro collection (LaTeX or ConTeXt). Even in plain LuaTEX keys can be parsed.
- luakeys can handle nested lists of key-value pairs, i.e. it can handle a recursive data structure of keys.
- Keys do not have to be defined, but can they can be defined.

### Cons

- The package works only in combination with LuaTeX.
- You need to know two languages: TeX and Lua.

Answer (score 0):

## [rkeyval.sty](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs)

Author: Michael Downes

Keyval syntax is restricted in a sense that options must always be surrounded by braces.