# Creating an environment that uses macros

Tags: macros, environments

I have a macro that requires some setup code before being called :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
% some setup code
\colorbox{green}{This is green.}
% some cleanup code
\end{document}
```

All is good, but I don't like duplicating the setup/cleanup code.

How can I get a similar result using Environments? That way I could place the setup code in the "begin" section and the cleanup in the "end" section.

I tried the following, but obviously that's not how it works :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}

% % % % THIS DOES NOT WORK % % % %
\newenvironment{green}{\colorbox{green}\begingroup}{\endgroup}
% % % % THIS DOES NOT WORK % % % %

\begin{document}

\begin{green}
This should be green as well.
\end{green}

\end{document}
```

This gives the error `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` I tought that `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` were specifically for using in unbalanced situations.

What are my options?

Comment: In Lieu of my bad answer, let me leave my original comment: `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` only help if you want a group.  To get unbalanced braces, one technique is to use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, which are `\let` to `{` and `}`, but this doesn't help with macro arguments.  It does help with (most) boxes, but that's special.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can use the `lrbox` environment to collect the contents.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}


\newenvironment{green}
{\begin{lrbox}{0}}
{\end{lrbox}\colorbox{green}{\usebox{0}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{green}
This should be green as well.
\end{green}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for long piece of texts with linebreaks in it though. How could one go in that case (without using `environ`)?

Comment: @glS it uses colorbox as the OP requested, if you need a multi-line box then you need to nest minipage inside the lrbox, as usual.

Comment: but with `minipage` you get that if you started the environment in the middle of a line the whole text in the environment starts from the middle of the line

Answer (score 6):

You can manage environments in a similar way you would macros by means of [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor

\NewEnviron{green}{\colorbox{green}{\BODY}}%

\begin{document}

\colorbox{green}{This should be green as well.}

\begin{green}
This should be green as well.
\end{green}

\end{document}
```

The environment contents is grabbed and stored in `\BODY`, which can then be passed to a macro. However, this does not support boxing `verbatim` content, something an `lrbox`-approach does.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers fully address  the OP's question quite well, no one has mentioned the use of keys.  I would take an approach very similar to @DavidCarlisle (though I also like @Werner 's approach too).  But, I would create keys to manage the color (and possibly other *set up material*) to allow me to change the color later in the document for a particular use.

The OP's comment about *set up* code is what got me thinking about keys.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{/jt/colored/box/.cd,
  color/.initial = green,
}

\newsavebox{\mycolorBox}
\newenvironment{mycolor}[1][green]
  {\pgfkeys{/jt/colored/box/.cd,color=#1}%%'
   \begin{lrbox}{\mycolorBox}}
  {\end{lrbox}%%'
   \colorbox
     {\pgfkeysvalueof{/jt/colored/box/color}}%%'
     {\usebox{\mycolorBox}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

   \begin{mycolor}
    Green box
   \end{mycolor}

   \begin{mycolor}[blue!20]
    Blue box
   \end{mycolor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding keys, there are many nice packages out there for dealing with keys.  Recently, I've been experimenting a lot with `pgfkeys` or working with `l3keys`.  But there's also many other such packages:  see [A  big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26771/22413) details about other possible key-value packages

Comment: I don't think those `\expandafter`'s are necessary, as accessing the value requires two expansion steps.

Comment: @egreg You're right!  Somehow things weren't working until I put those in.  I must have inadvertently fixed the bug when I modified my code.