# Boolean key value in xkeyval fails

Tags: programming, package-writing, etoolbox, xkeyval

It is possible to hand over a boolean key value stored in a macro to a command
such as

```
\edef\SomeKeyValue{true}%

\DummyCommand[DummyBooleanKey=\SomeKeyValue]%%%
```

where DummyBooleanKey is a boolean key defined via

```
\define@boolkey{SomeKeys}{DummyBooleanKey}[false]{%%%% etc.
```

However, it fails when I try to compile following MNWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\define@boolkey{SomeKeys}{DummyBoolKey}[false]{%
\ifKV@SomeKeys@DummyBoolKey%
\typeout{true}%
\else%
\typeout{false}%
\fi%
}%


% Key Family is called SomeKeys

% Use a fake command for testing purposes

\providecommand{\DummyCommand}[1][false]{%

\setkeys{SomeKeys}{#1}%

% Do something useful inside this command...

}%

\edef\SomeKeyValue{true}%

\begin{document}

% Works
\DummyCommand[DummyBoolKey=true]%

% Does not work!
\DummyCommand[DummyBoolKey={\SomeKeyValue}]%


\end{document}
```

How is it possible to use a literal `true` or `false` value as key value parameter? Do I have to use `newtoks` in order to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Keyval implements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package) tend to be very careful *not* to expand input 'out of order', and thus the problem you see is not `xkeyval`-specific. For keys which take a fixed list of choices, which includes boolean keys, this deliberate behaviour means that

```
\def\myvariable{some-valid-input}
\KeySettingCommand{valid-key-name=\myvariable}
```

will not work. As a result, you need to either store both the key and value and pre-expand:

```
\def\myvariable{valid-key-name=some-valid-input}
\expandafter\KeySettingCommand\expandafter{\myvariable}
```

or store the entire keyval construct:

```
\def\myvariable{\KeySettingCommand{valid-key-name=some-valid-input}}
\myvariable
```

Note that using `\edef` makes no difference here: it carries out expansion at *point of definition*, not *point of use*.

Answer (score 7):

When `\setkeys` examines the key-value pairs it does *no* expansion; something like

```
\begin{itemize}[label=\arabic*]
```

would tragically fail if this was used. So, in your second case, `\SomeKeyValue` is passed without any expansion as the value for `DummyBoolKey` and it's illegal, because this key wants either `true` or `false` (or nothing at all, which would be equivalent to `false`, by your definition).

Doing

```
\edef\SomeKeyValue{true}
```

doesn't help, because this is perfectly equivalent to `\def\SomeKeyValue{true}`, since none of the tokens in `true` is expandable.

If your values never contain symbolic tokens (expandable tokens, actually), you can define differently `\DummyCommand`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DummyCommand}[1][false]{%
  \begingroup\protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\setkeys{SomeKeys}{#1}}\x
  % Do something useful inside this command...
}
\makeatother
```

However, this would break badly in cases the options are like those in the `itemize` example.