# Key value options in combination with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, key-value

I'm trying to create some TikZ commands that use key value options. Using the following link:
[How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values)
I was able to declare some commands, but now I'm stuck.

As a MWE consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter

% using keyval package
\define@key{cutkv}{label}{\def\cutkv@label{#1}}
\define@key{cutkv}{bend}{\def\cutkv@bend{#1}}
\setkeys{cutkv}{label={},bend={}}
\newcommand{\cutkv}[3][]{
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{cutkv}{#1}
  \draw[->] (#2) to[\cutkv@bend] node{\cutkv@label} (#3);
  \endgroup
}

% using pgfkeys package
\pgfkeys{
  /cutpgf/.is family, /cutpgf,
  default/.style =
  {label = ,
   bend = },
  label/.estore in = \cutpgf@label,
  bend/.estore in = \cutpgf@bend,
}
\newcommand{\cutpgf}[3][]{
  \pgfkeys{/cutpgf, default, #1}
  \draw[->] (#2) to[\cutpgf@bend] node{\cutpgf@label} (#3);
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cutkv[label=1]{0,0}{3,5}
  \cutkv[label=2,bend={bend right}]{1,4}{7,2}
  \cutkv[label=3,bend={bend right=10}]{6,0}{5,4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cutpgf[label=1]{0,0}{3,5}
  \cutpgf[label=2,bend={bend right}]{1,4}{7,2}
  \cutpgf[label=3,bend={bend right=10}]{6,0}{5,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first and the second call of the \cut command work fine, but in the third call the option `bend right=10` is not passed correctly. At least, I don't understand the problem there.

I also tried the approach with `pgfkeys`, as mentioned in the first answer of the above post, but that didn't change anything.

edit: I added the version with `pgfkeys` to the MWE.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `pgfkeys` approach is different to `keyval` or `xkeyval` package, they do not co-operate, unfortunately.

Comment: As I said, I also tried it with `pgfkeys` instead of `keyval`, but ended up with the same problem.

Comment: I tried your approaches, they fail too. I believe, the problem is quite similar to the one I posed in a question some weeks ago, perhaps the solution Joseph gave there is the `key` (sic!) to the problem: <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152020/boolean-key-value-in-xkeyval-fails> -- in my point of view the source of the error lies in the double '=' characters, one as the outer key assignment, the other one as the inner key assignment of the `pgfkeys`

Comment: I thought `{...}` would take care of that, but you might be right, adding a list of options like `opt={thick,dashed}` is not working neither.

Comment: @Christian Yes, same issue but here `\expandafter` is tricky so I've used `\edef` in an answer

Comment: @JosephWright: `keyval` packages are quite tricky.

Comment: @Christian Not really in this case: it's nothing to do with mixing packages, it's all about expansion. That's a TeX 'thing'.

Comment: @JosephWright: I did not mean the mixing of the packages, but the `TeX` thing, you stated more precisely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, this is nothing to do with the choice of keyval method but is instead due to the fact that keyval processors do *not* expand their input (in general). You need to force expansion, here probably easiest to do using `\edef`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter

% using keyval package
\define@key{cutkv}{label}{\def\cutkv@label{#1}}
\define@key{cutkv}{bend}{\def\cutkv@bend{#1}}
\setkeys{cutkv}{label={},bend={}}
\newcommand{\cutkv}[3][]{
  \begingroup
  \setkeys{cutkv}{#1}
  \begingroup
    \edef\x
    {%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\draw[->] (#2) to[\cutkv@bend] node{\cutkv@label} (#3);
    }\x
  \endgroup
}

% using pgfkeys package
\pgfkeys{
  /cutpgf/.is family, /cutpgf,
  default/.style =
  {label = ,
   bend = },
  label/.estore in = \cutpgf@label,
  bend/.estore in = \cutpgf@bend,
}
\newcommand{\cutpgf}[3][]{%
  \pgfkeys{/cutpgf, default, #1}%
  \begingroup
    \edef\x{%
      \endgroup
      \noexpand\draw[->] (#2) to[\cutpgf@bend] node{\cutpgf@label} (#3);
    }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cutkv[label=1]{0,0}{3,5}
  \cutkv[label=2,bend={bend right}]{1,4}{7,2}
  \cutkv[label=3,bend={bend right=10}]{6,0}{5,4}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \cutpgf[label=1]{0,0}{3,5}
  \cutpgf[label=2,bend={bend right}]{1,4}{7,2}
  \cutpgf[label=3,bend={bend right=10}]{6,0}{5,4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the idea is that the `\draw` line needs to have the full expansion of your variables: by using `\edef` I don't have to worry about carefully counting tokens for `\expandafter`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your solution and extended it a bit to my needs and it works perfectly.

Comment: Now, I found some unwanted side effects with `\noexpand`. If I change the `draw`command to `\noexpand\draw[->] (#2) to[\cutkv@bend] node{\tiny \cutkv@label} (#3);` I get errors, I can't solve.

Comment: @stephanboehme Expansion is tricky: most LaTeX2e commands cannot be safely used inside `\edef`. Here, you'll need a `\noexpand` before `\tiny` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks again, it's working nicely now. And even with not completely understanding the expansion-`\edef`-`\noexpand`-issue, I get a feeling for it :)