# Reason not to use a specific key val package

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value, xkeyval, l3keys

According to the very nice list of packages concerning this topic ([A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package))

I am confused which package I should use now to be prepared for the future.

Any ideas which approach I should follow? Currently I am using kvoptions, but I have to redesign some code and than I would like to decide the best option....

Question: Which package should I use in no case?

Update 1: According to Joseph Writes comment below:
First approach: Writing a general class, which adresses the following approach.
    Any package will be controlled be the class, if xetex will be used, packages wont be load if the are not compatible. If a class beamer is loaded the same.
    also: titlepage on of, which titlepage,
    also: ogc used yes or no
    also: glossar, yes or no
    also: watermarks, yes or no
    ...

Second Approach: 
    Writing a autotable package, which uses csv files as source and make nice tables which predefined table layouts. Autorecognition of columncounts, determine best fit to page. Can handle multipage. Can handle more than one csv and different packages should be bundled to one package, if required.
    supports ocgx2 for multipage sortable tables.

Comment: You might want to outline your scenario: for example, if you are loading `pgf` for graphics anyway then `pgfkeys` makes perhaps most sense.

Comment: Hm, this question is a little bit `opinion` based. For a normal usage I prefer `xkeyval`, for developing new packages with `expl3` the `l3keys` approach is of course better. Mixing is difficult, however

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a workflow depending on the compilation. You might better off with creating if branches instead of keys. It might be the case that you are used to Python like keywords but key based branching is not that useful.

Comment: I can't stand **xkeyval** although some of my stuff still uses it in whole or in part. I like **l3keys** but only where that's an option, of course. Basically, now I use **l3keys** and **pgfkeys** for PGF/TikZ stuff and `\if...` toggles where those fail me. But I don't know this is ***better***. It is just ***easier***. It is relatively intelligible, whereas **xkeyval** is even less intelligible than **keyval**. But, obviously, that's definitely an opinion. If other people understand (**x**) **keyval**, good luck to them ;).

Comment: Don't attempt (1) at all. Definitely don't attempt a class designed as either Beamer or something else. That way madness lies. And it is entirely opposed to the general direction L3 seems to be thinking in and that L2 was thinking in to a lesser degree i.e. one class per task. In those terms, a general class becomes an oxymoron. So, in terms of future-proofing, I'd think don't do it. But JW didn't say not to, so I'm surely mistaken.

Comment: @cfr I dont understand. I only take an argument to provide the classname and than the original class is loaded...providing a function that generate a class as single template. Which can be tested.
I do not want to have one class for all purposes. But I would like to have a class where I can switch to another class and want to use all functions which are available.

Comment: That sounds like a single class to me. But maybe I don't understand as I have no idea what you mean about generating one as `single template`, whether it can be tested or not. I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: Can you tell me, where I can diskuss this topic with the community, providing a MWE?