# How to use keyword arguments in a LaTeX environment?

Tags: environments

I would like to define a convenient way to pass arguments to an environment using the notation `key=value`. I don't know how to find this on the documentation.

For exemple:

```
\newenvironment{foobar}[3]{
...
}

\begin{foobar}[foo=1,bar=2,baz=3]
    text1
\end{foobar}

\begin{foobar}[bar=10]
    text2
\end{foobar}
```

And the result could be:

```
begin_foobar
you said that foo equals 1, bar equals 2 and baz equals 3
text1
end_foobar

begin_foobar
you said that bar equals 10
text2
end_foobar
```

(if you have any advise for a good documentation about LaTeX plumbery, I take it)

Comment: Use one of the many packages providing this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package (I use normally l3keys, which is now already included in the latex format, but I'm biased).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The [manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/l3keys2e.pdf) is very small. Do you have any idea how I should use it? Where can I find a good documentation with some examples?

Comment: that is the manual of l3keys2e, l3keys is described in the expl3 manual "interface3". If you search a bit on the site here you can find many examples. (And as I wrote: I'm biased. Perhaps for a start you should at first try keyval, to get used to key-val definitions.)

Comment: why should I get the credit if you did the work?

Answer (score 2):

Here an example of what you can do, using the [`keyval`](https://texdoc.org/serve/keyval.pdf/0) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myenv@keys}{foo}{\def\myenv@foo{#1}}%
\define@key{myenv@keys}{bar}{\def\myenv@bar{#1}}%

\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]{%
    \setkeys{myenv@keys}{foo=4,bar=4,#1}
    Foo=\myenv@foo\par
    Bar=\myenv@bar\par
    Before\par
}{
    After
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[foo=42]
    Inside
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[bar=42]
    Inside
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{foobar}{O{}}
 {
  \par
  \nowox_foobar_init:n { #1 }
 }
 {
  \par
 }

\keys_define:nn { nowox/foobar }
 {
  foo .tl_set:N = \l_nowox_foobar_foo_tl,
  bar .tl_set:N = \l_nowox_foobar_bar_tl,
  baz .tl_set:N = \l_nowox_foobar_baz_tl,
 }

\seq_new:N \l__nowox_foobar_args_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nowox_foobar_arg_add:nn
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nF { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__nowox_foobar_args_seq
     {
      #1~equals~#2
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nowox_foobar_arg_add:nn { nV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nowox_foobar_init:n
 {
  \keys_set:nn { nowox/foobar } { #1 }
  \__nowox_foobar_arg_add:nV {foo} \l_nowox_foobar_foo_tl
  \__nowox_foobar_arg_add:nV {bar} \l_nowox_foobar_bar_tl
  \__nowox_foobar_arg_add:nV {baz} \l_nowox_foobar_baz_tl
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l__nowox_foobar_args_seq
   {
    you~said~that~\seq_use:Nnnn \l__nowox_foobar_args_seq { ~and~ } { ,~ } { ~and~ } \par
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{foobar}[foo=1,bar=2,baz=3]
    text1
\end{foobar}

\begin{foobar}[bar=10]
    text2
\end{foobar}

\begin{foobar}
    text3
\end{foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The keys are set locally, so they don't change their empty status at the beginning. The nonempty values are added to a sequence that can be “used” with different text between entries (a comma between two, “and” between only two and ”and” between the last two, if more than two.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @nowox's answer, I've added macro definitions that allow the key values to be used within the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{myenv@keys}{foo}{\def\myenv@foo{#1}}%
\define@key{myenv@keys}{bar}{\def\myenv@bar{#1}}%
\newenvironment{myenv}[1][]{%
    % \makeatletter
    \setkeys{myenv@keys}{foo=default foo,% Set default value for foo
                         bar=default bar,% Set default value for bar
                         #1}% Set values given in environment argument.
    \def\foo{\myenv@foo}% Define \foo as the value given.
    \def\bar{\myenv@bar}% Probably a bad idea to redefine \bar, but done for sake of demo.

    In environment preamble: foo=``\foo'', bar=``\bar.''\par
}{
    \par\bigskip
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatother
\begin{myenv}[foo=hello]
    % Within the environment, \foo and \bar can used.
    In environment (1): \verb|\foo|=``\foo'', \verb|\bar|=``\bar.''
\end{myenv}


\begin{myenv}[bar=goodbye]
    In environment (2): \verb|\foo|=``\foo'', \verb|\bar|=``\bar.''
\end{myenv}

Outside the \verb|myenv| environment, \verb|\foo| is undefined 
and \verb|\bar| retains its original definition meaning, 
e.g., \verb|\bar{A}=|$\bar{A}$.

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]