# Declare new command to denote the condition with additional settings

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, conditionals, definition

Can someone tell me how to set the parameters of a declared new command similar to how it is set in the `TikZ` package? More specifically, I would like to declare a function `\condVert{}` that sets a vertical line to the right of the selected expression (environment `\left.` + `\right|`) indicating a condition (or the limits of a variable change). Also, as an additional parameter, I would like to set the ability to set brackets / frames around the expression.

Examples:

| Command | Result | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `\condVert[lim={x=0 | a}]{f(x)}` | [image] |  |
| `\condVert[limits={x=0 | a}]{f(x)}` | [image] | *lim* and *limits* in the settings should give the same result. |
| `\condVert[lim={x=a}, angle bracs]{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}` | [image] | I would also like to be able to use syntax like [...*brackets=angle*]. |
| `\condVert[lim={x=a}, rangle bracs]{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}` | [image] |  |
| `\condVert[lim={x=a}, {dash box}]{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}` | [image] |  |
| `\condVert[lim={x=a}, {dash circle box}]{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}` | [image] |  |

Highlighting the background color would probably be too expressive, but perhaps it would be good to add to the functionality. :)

Comment: You want to learn LaTeX programming? There are `keyval` package (and other packages like `keyvalx` etc., and of course TikZ programming layer (pgf), and expl3's  `l3keys` package (read interface3.pdf for this one) [key value - A big list of every keyval package - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package)

Comment: If it doesn't make sense to you, start with [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming) (warning: long journey)

Comment: My package [SemanTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex) was made more or less exactly for commands like this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution via my own, slightly non-standard package, [SemanTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/semantex?). I took the liberty to change the order and meaning of some arguments and keys in a way that made the implementation easier:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\condVert[
    define keys[2]={
        {limits}{
            Other spar={.}{|}{auto},
            lower={#1},
            upper={#2},
        },
    },
    define keys[1]={
        {lim}{ limits={#1}{} },
    },
    define keys={
        {angle bracs}{
            Other spar={(}{)}{auto},
        },
        {rangle bracs}{
            Other spar={[}{]}{auto},
        },
        {dash box}{
            command=\dashboxcommand,
        },
        {dash circle box}{
            command=\dashcircleboxcommand,
        },
    },
]

\newcommand\dashboxcommand[1]{%
    #1% change to suit your needs
}

\newcommand\dashcircleboxcommand[1]{%
    #1% change to suit your needs
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \condVert{f(x)}[lim={x=0}]
\\
    \condVert{f(x)}[limits={x=0}{a}]
\\
    \condVert{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}[angle bracs,lim={x=a}]
\\
    \condVert{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}[rangle bracs,lim={x=a}]
\\
    \condVert{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}[dash box, lim={x=a}]
\\
    \condVert{\dfrac{x^2}{2} + x}[dash circle box, lim={x=a}]
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this will be a good help for my needs. :) Of course, I'd like to know the solution by native TeX methods, without involving third-party packages.

Comment: @Sssur I’m not really sure what you even mean by “native TeX methods” vs. “third-party packages”. LaTeX itself is a third-party package to TeX, and TikZ is a third-party package to both LaTeX and plain TeX. Unless you are a masochist, then trust me, you do not want to create your own keyval parser from scratch using plain TeX commands. You will have to rely on some other package like `l3keys`, `keyval`, `pgfkeys`, or `expkv`. The first one is now built into LaTeX and is therefore the closest thing you get to a “first-party” keyval implementation. SemanTeX is indirectly based on `l3keys`.