# How to use equals sign in custom class options?

Tags: document-classes, latex-base

I have seen package options such as in `geometry` that allow the user to specify an option with a certain value. For example, `\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}` will use `1in` for the left and right margins. Is this possible to do in my own custom class? Say I want to specify the margins in the class, such as `\documentclass[margin=1in]{myclass}`. How would I do this? I know how to pass in regular options, such as `option`, but not ones that have a value, such as `option=value`.

Comment: Probably something in [key value - A big list of every keyval package - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package) -- but depends on how you're already doing things it might be easier to use the same library you're already using...?

Comment: @user202729 a big list of every package misses then no-package version though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Probably we should add an answer there or at least modify the `l3keys` one?

Comment: separate answer I think @JosephWright

Answer (score 12):

[image]

For old releases packages providing this are available, but in the current release it is built in, see ltnews35.

`myc.cls`

---

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2022-06-01]
\ProvidesClass{myc}[2022-06-17]

\RequirePackage{xcolor}


\DeclareKeys{
color.code = \colorlet{foocol}{#1},
val.store = \fooval
}


\SetKeys{
color =black,
val=0
}

\ProcessKeyOptions

\setlength\textwidth{6cm}
\setlength\textheight{8cm}

\renewcommand\normalsize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
```

---

`file.tex`

---

```
\documentclass[color=red,val=42]{myc}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{foocol}{one}  $x=\fooval$
\end{document}
```

Comment: is there a more detail documentation for the new built-in commands, including uses with tests for example? The ltnews35 blurb is quite lacking for people who, like me, have not followed closely l3 development.

Comment: `texdoc souce2e` has information  (ltkeys chapter) and we have an _intention_ (not done yet) to update `clsguide`   The `l3keys2e` package doc also covers the main ideas, but with some changes in command names.@ArTourter

Comment: Thanks David! I did look at the `l3keys2e` doc but left me none the wiser:-) The `source2e` is more helpful indeed. I will keep an eye on the `clsguide` though.

Comment: One should note that keys defined via `expl3`'s `\keys_define:nn` also work with `\ProcessKeyOptions`, and that currently more different key-types are available with the `expl3` names.

Answer (score 5):

`mycls.cls`

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mycls}[2022-06-17]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn{test}
{
  name.tl_set:N = \l_name_tl,
  age.int_set:N = \l_age_int,
}
\ProcessKeysOptions{test}
\def\myinfo{my~name~is~\tl_use:N \l_name_tl,and~i~am~\int_use:N \l_age_int ~years~old.}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

`main.tex`

```tex
\documentclass[name = {ljguo},age = 12]{mycls}
\begin{document}
  \myinfo
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 yes `l3keys2e` is a good choice if needed to work on previous releases as it  gives a very simple update path to switch later to the new built-in option handler, as it is essentially the same code, but with an older interface: note `s`  in `\ProcessKeysOptions` not `\ProcessKeyOptions`  and use of `_ ` and `:` names for  the key types, compared to my answer using the new format version.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses `expkv-opt` (and defines keys using the `expkv-def` frontend).

`myc.cls`

---

```
\ProvidesClass{myc}[2022-06-18]

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{expkv-opt,expkv-def}
\ekvdefinekeys{myc}
  {%
     code    color = \colorlet{foocol}{#1}
    ,initial color = black
    ,store   val   = \fooval
    ,initial val   = 0
    ,store   size  = \foosize
    ,initial size  = 10
  }

\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions{myc}
\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{myc}

\renewcommand\normalsize
  {%
    \fontsize{\foosize}{\strip@pt\dimexpr1.2\dimexpr\foosize pt\relax\relax}%
    \selectfont
  }

\newcommand*\myctest
  {\rule{.4pt}{7pt}Options were: \textcolor{foocol}{\fooval}\rule{.4pt}{7pt}}
```

---

`file.tex`

---

```
\documentclass[color=red, val=42, size=14]{myc}

\begin{document}
\myctest
\end{document}
```

---

Result:

---

[image]

---