# How can I highlight certain argument fields

Tags: environments, arguments

I have this environment with 9 arguments. I want to highlight some of the inputs of the argument (#1). Is it possible to do so?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Kalpurush}

\newenvironment{word}[9]% environment name
{
    \fbox{#1}\hspace{0.2cm}\textit{#2}---#3\ifstrempty{#4}{}{\textbengali{ / #4}}\newline
    \ifstrempty{#9}{}{ex: \textbf{\textit{``#9''}}\\}
    \ifstrempty{#5}{}{n: #5\\}
    \ifstrempty{#6}{}{v: #6\\}
    \ifstrempty{#7}{}{adj: #7\\}
    \ifstrempty{#8}{}{adv: #8\\}
    \newline
}{}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{January 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}
    \section{31/05/2022}
    \begin{word}
        {269}{irrefutable}{impossible to deny or disprove}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \end{word}
    \begin{word}
        {270}{asunder}{apart}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \end{word}
    \begin{word}
        {271}{parables}{short story about moral attitude}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \end{word}
    \begin{word}
        {272}{propound}{put forward / offer}{}{}{}{}{}{}
    \end{word}
    \end{multicols}
    
\end{document}
```

I want to mark some numbers automatically by putting those in a separate file or in the same file like this **[269,271 and so on]**

Comment: Could you extend your code fragment into a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please, it will help you get an answer if you make it as easy as possible for people to help :)

Comment: Please note that `\newenvironment` requires three arguments (plus two optional ones for the number of arguments and the default value of the first if it should be optional), so correct would be `\newenvironment{<name>}{<code-in-begin>}{<code-in-end>}`, it looks like your use only has the first two (and works by accident because there is an implicit `\par` following because of the two consecutive newlines).

Comment: @Skillmon Sorry! I forgot to add the `{end_def}`. I have edited my code. There is no default value for the first argument as it is mandatory.

Comment: Another thing: You might want to think about a key=value interface instead of 9 consecutive arguments, named parameters are usually easier to memorise and use than positional ones.

Comment: @Skillmon I don't know about the key=value interface.

Comment: There are different variants of key=value interfaces in LaTeX. There is a list [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package). I myself prefer my own package (duh), the ones that are worth a look in that list, imho, are: "LaTeX kernel" (or "l3keys.sty" as they are the same under the hood), "expkv" (this is mine), "pgfkeys.sty".