# Is there a way to add optional and/or named argument to command

Tags: macros, formatting, errors, optional-arguments, arguments

I'm writing a handbook for my students and I want to create a command which should draw a task definition, its type and possible features, like source and link to the solution on YouTube.

In my plan all of these definitions should work (of course I use pseudo syntax here on purpose, just to show you my intention):

- `\task{definition=$x=3$}`
- `\task{definition=$x=3$, source='ABC'}`
- `\task{definition=$x=3$, link='https://youtube.ru'}`
- `\task{definition=$x=3$, source='ABC', link='https://youtube.ru'}`

But I cannot find any tool similar to optional and named arguments.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/106162) and [A big list of every keyval package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26771/106162)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Ignore the Community Bot.  Sometimes it doesn't know what it's talking about.

Comment: Welcome. // Using the keyvalue approach is certainly the most flexible. If you want to stick with the standard `\newcommand`, you may want to provide default values. See e.g. here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros#New_commands . // Hint: you may also find the column to the right helpful (Linked, Related)

Comment: @campa I wouldn't have deleted your answer! (voted to undelete)

Comment: Seconding @DavidCarlisle's undelete. Aside from anything else, `keyval` has backwards compatibility with older LaTeX in its favour.

Comment: @campa My comment was not meant as criticism, but merely as a discussion about the best solutions in 2023, and the pros and cons of pre-expl3 packages such as `keyval`. I certainly didn’t intend for you to delete the answer. 

Comment: @Gaussler The advantage of pre-expl3 packages is that I understand them (Grumpy Old Man talking here `;-)`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Classically the LaTeX2e solution was the `keyval` package (as used by `\includegraphics[height=2cm, scale=3]{...}`)  but recent LaTeX releases include a keyval parser built in, based on `l3keys`.

@Campa's example modified to use the newer system:

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\DeclareKeys[task]{
definition .store = \task@definition,
source     .store = \task@source,
link       .store = \task@link
}



\NewDocumentCommand\task{m}{%
   \begingroup
   \SetKeys[task]{#1}%
   This is a task with definition \task@definition.%
   \ifx\task@source\@empty\else\space You can find its source in \task@source.\fi
   \ifx\task@link\@empty\else\space (See \task@link)\fi
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition={$x=3$}}\par % you must "hide" the =
\task{definition={$x=3$}, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition={$x=3$}, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition={$x=3$}, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition={$x=3$}} % you must "hide" the =
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be a start using `keyval`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\task@definition}{}
\newcommand*{\task@source}{}
\newcommand*{\task@link}{}
\define@key{task}{definition}{\def\task@definition{#1}}
\define@key{task}{source}{\def\task@source{#1}}
\define@key{task}{link}{\def\task@link{#1}}
\newcommand*{\task}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \setkeys{task}{#1}%
   This is a task with definition \task@definition.%
   \ifx\task@source\@empty\else\space You can find its source in \task@source.\fi
   \ifx\task@link\@empty\else\space (See \task@link)\fi
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition={$x=3$}}\par % you must "hide" the =
\task{definition={$x=3$}, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition={$x=3$}, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition={$x=3$}, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition={$x=3$}} % you must "hide" the =
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure the `keyval` package is the right solution to recommend in 2023.

Comment: @Gaussler IMO that's still the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 4):

For a simple task, imho<sup>1</sup>, nothing beats the simplicity of `expkv-cs` and `\ekvcSplit` (this only works for up to 9 keys, for more it's most likely better to use methods from `expkv-def` which work similar to `\DeclareKeys` -- or another key=value implementation like the one built into LaTeX).

<sub><sup>1</sup>I'm the author of `expkv` and family.</sub>

To have an easy way to add formatting instructions and extra text to a key one can use a front facing key that decorates some internal key. So every time you say `link = www.example.com` this becomes `link-internal={ (See www.example.com)}`.

Also in `expkv` you don't have to hide an additional `=`, but you'd have to hide a `,`.

This borrows the example created by @campa and modifies it to use `expkv-cs`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcSplit\task
  {
    % set up primary keys, all defaulting to an empty value
     definition = {}
    ,source-internal = {}
    ,link-internal = {}
  }
  {This is a task with definition #1.#2#3}
% set up decorators
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\task
  {
     meta source = {source-internal = { You can find its source in #1.}}
    ,meta link   = {link-internal   = { (See #1)}}
  }

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition=$x=3$}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition=$x=3$}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively to the `\ekvcSplit` version, you could also use the `\ekvcHash` version, in which you can access the key-values by name (the entire list will be forwarded inside of `#1`, and `\ekvcValue` can be used to access items from that list -- this works for arbitrary many keys).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcHash\task
  {
    % set up primary keys, all defaulting to an empty value
     definition = {}
    ,source-internal = {}
    ,link-internal = {}
  }
  {%
    This is a task with definition \ekvcValue{definition}{#1}.%
    \ekvcValue{source-internal}{#1}%
    \ekvcValue{link-internal}{#1}%
  }
% set up decorators
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\task
  {
     meta source = {source-internal = { You can find its source in #1.}}
    ,meta link   = {link-internal   = { (See #1)}}
  }

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition=$x=3$}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition=$x=3$}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want an interface closer to the one provided by `\DeclareKeys` you could use `expkv-def`. In addition to a `store`-handler it also provides `dataT`. The instruction `dataT link = \taskLink` will define `\taskLink` such that by default it'll gobble the next token or brace-group, but if the key was used it'll put the value as `{<value>}` behind the next token or brace-group (and would strip the braces from that following brace-group).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{task}
  {
     store definition = \taskDefinition
    ,dataT source     = \taskSource
    ,dataT link       = \taskLink
  }
\newcommand\taskSourceFormatter[1]{ You can find its source in #1.}
\newcommand\taskLinkFormatter[1]{ (See #1)}

\newcommand\task[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \ekvset{task}{#1}%
      This is a task with definition \taskDefinition.%
      \taskSource\taskSourceFormatter
      \taskLink\taskLinkFormatter
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition=$x=3$}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition=$x=3$}
\end{document}
```

---

And if you really want to, you could use basically the same syntax as for `keyval` by using the basic `expkv` without any of the extension packages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\newcommand*\taskDefinition{}
\newcommand*\taskSource{}
\newcommand*\taskLink{}
\ekvdef{task}{definition}{\def\taskDefinition{#1}}
\ekvdef{task}{source}{\def\taskSource{#1}}
\ekvdef{task}{link}{\def\taskLink{#1}}

\newcommand\task[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \ekvset{task}{#1}%
      This is a task with definition \taskDefinition.%
      \ifx\taskSource\empty\else\space You can find its source in \taskSource.\fi
      \ifx\taskLink\empty\else\space (See \taskLink)\fi
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\task{definition=$x=3$}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, link=https://youtube.ru}\par
\task{definition=$x=3$, source=ABC, link=https://youtube.ru}
\task{definition=$x=3$}
\end{document}
```

---

Result of all code blocks:

[image]